# ZF2 Event Trigger

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm having an issue getting an event to trigger. Here is my code...

controller.php

```
function get($id) 
{
    $this->getEventManager()->trigger('hmac.check');
}
```

When this trigger is ran it will not run the hmac.check event even though it is attached.

module.php

```
class Module
{
    /**
     * Init the methods
     *
     * @param ModuleManager $moduleManager
     */
    public function init(ModuleManager $mm)
    {
        $mm->getEventManager()
           ->attach(
               'hmac.check',
               function(MvcEvent $evt)
               {
                   echo "The trigger has worked";
                   $key = $evt->getParams()->fromHeader('key');
                   $ts = $evt->getParams()->fromHeader('when');
                   $uri = $evt->getParams()->fromHeader('uri');

                   $hmac = new \Scc\Hmac\Hmac(new HmacConfig, new HmacStorage);
               }
        );
    }
}
```

If i echo out a message before or after the $mm->getEventManager->attach(); it displays the test fine so i know it is executing the init method.

any help with this would be great.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is a restful controller if that makes any difference (i don't think it does).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're attaching listeners to the `ModuleManager`s `EventManager` instance, and not the main `Application` EventManager.

There's no way to attach to the Application EventManager directly from module init(), the module manager doesn't have access to it, so you need to instead get the SharedManager from the ModuleManager's EventManager and attach your event listeners to that.

Here's an example of doing that by listening to the `hmac.check` event when triggered by any controller that extends `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController`, but you could listen to a specific controller by replacing that with your controllers FQCN instead.

```
class Module
{
    /**
     * Init the methods
     *
     * @param ModuleManager $moduleManager
     */
    public function init(ModuleManager $mm)
    {
        $mm->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
           ->attach(
               'Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController', 'hmac.check',
               function(MvcEvent $evt)
               {
                   echo "The trigger has worked";
                   $key = $evt->getParams()->fromHeader('key');
                   $ts = $evt->getParams()->fromHeader('when');
                   $uri = $evt->getParams()->fromHeader('uri');

                   $hmac = new \Scc\Hmac\Hmac(new HmacConfig, new HmacStorage);
               }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get this working? I got the following error: Argument 1 passed to closure must be an instance of Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent, instance of Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent given

Comment: @emolah, if you're getting a ModuleEvent instance, I can only assume that you copied the code used in the question, instead of the code given in the answer.

Comment: any way to do the same but w/o attaching it to a specific controller?   like, maybe every controller can trigger this event?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco if you take a look at the answer, it's listening to all classes extending the AbstractRestfulController class, not a specific controller class. You could just as easily replace that with  `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController` and listen to all action controller instances instead (assuming your action controllers follow normal ZF2 convention and extend the AbstractActionController).